# Set different settings for different Wi-Fi networks

Tags: wifi

Can I set IP address manually on one Wi-Fi network and "Using DHCP" for another? So when I connect to the first one my mac uses static IP, when I connect to 2nd one - use DHCP.

Edit 1.

What I do all the time is.
When I come at work I set DHCP for Wi-Fi.
When I come home I set "manually" and specify IP, subnet mask, and router.
I don't have problems with Proxies. I need to setup my Mac's IPs correctly.

Edit 2.
Location works just fine. 
Thanks to people in comments.

Comment: More or less a duplicate but for sure related: [How to quick switch OSX proxy on/off?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/89214/how-to-quick-switch-osx-proxy-on-off). Defining locations works also for different Wi-Fi networks.

Comment: Nothing related. I don't see how I can set specific IP address for one Wi-Fi network and use DHCP for another.

Comment: Andrii, did you try https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/287690/9058 ? This should work for all kind of network settings, not just for proxies.

Comment: nohillside, this sounds like the answer to my problem. I'll check it today when get home.

Comment: If you can't get it to work, please *edit* your question to show what you did and flag for mod attention again.

Comment: I didn't mean the proxy part but the locations part. Simply configure two different locations: 1. Wi-Fi DHCP or *Work* 2. Wi-Fi manual or *Home*. In the first location configure the DHCP Wi-Fi with DHCP and in the second the other Wi-Fi with a manual IP.