# How to add button to Safari Toolbar, that invokes AppleScript

Tags: applescript, safari, catalina

[ProxyToggle AppleScript](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/391127/187540):

```
set socksStatus to do shell script "networksetup -getsocksfirewallproxy Wi-fi | grep Enabled"

if (offset of "Yes" in socksStatus) = 0 then
    do shell script "networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxystate Wi-fi On"
    display notification "Proxy Enabled !"
else
    do shell script "networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxystate Wi-fi Off"
    display notification "Socks disabled"
    
end if
```

How to add a button to the toolbar that invokes above AppleScript?  Menu Item = View, `Customize Toolbar`.

[image]

Comment: I'd just use an **Automator** _Service/Quick Action_ and assign it a _keyboard shortcut_, e.g.: **⌥⌘P**

Comment: @user3439894 If you have a link that provides instructions, please to add link.  I am sure the community would like to see an example of such an option

Comment: gatorback, This has been covered ad nauseam on this site and the Internet and a **Google** search should provide many hits. Basically... Create an **Automator** _workflow_ of type _Service/Quick Action_ with setting **Service/Workflow receives no input in Safari** adding a **Run AppleScript** _action_ and your _code_. Save it and then give it a _keyboard shortcut_ in: **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services** -- **⌥⌘P** should work. -- Then provide appropriate permissions in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** as needed if/when prompted.